# Can UV outward space influences out of blender?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, coordinates

I am working on different objects in blender, I had made an old table on cycles , I ve marked seams and I have uploaded an image from internet to the "canvas image" of the new texture. There are an outward space beyond the limit of the UV space, I think is normal, I think is correct too, but that space is pixels after all? I think Unity or Unreal or some engine just read the information in pixel for the UV coordinates that I ve marked on blender.... and not for those area which I ve show in this picture.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "No matter the format, anyway to be loaded for rendering weighs the same as used in the memory as bitmap data. The format compresses only in storage.

Furthermore, the maps are independent uv texture because usually float values from 0 to 1 on the texture.

Rendering can only be optimized within the shaders d, but these are already well advanced and compiled efficiently in most engines, not worth worrying about this." Can be a good answer?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not very clear what you are asking. If you want to know if those empty areas affect game engine performace, then the naswer is that what matters is the total size of the texture. A bigger texture consumes more memory when uploaded into memory then a small texture, regardless if it is well used or not. Now if you have lots of empty areas in your UV map you are under-utilizing your texture space and wasting precious resources, without not gaining any performance

Comment: ok , but , what do you mean as empty areas? not pixels ? or space between UV island?

Comment: I meant space between UV Islands

Comment: I know something about texture bleeding, is necessary ,but in this case there are a whole image texture , it is a texture from cc public domain and this kind of texture occupied all the space beyont the uv island